# Add element to existing JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Hi I have the following JSON named departments. When i do console.log(departments) i get this.

```
{ _id: 58089a9c86337d1894ae1834,
  departmentName: 'Software Engineering',
  clientId: '57ff553e94542e1c2fd41d26',
  hodName: 'Mr Shekar Krishna',
  noOfEmployees: 90,
  hodId: 'djekjakejkjkjekajk3j33',
  __v: 0 }
```

But when i try to assign a value like hodId to a variable like this.

var hodId=departments.hodId;

and then do console.log i get undefined.

Also i need to add this value "hodId" to t to another JSON "user" which is currently like this:

```
{ fullName: 'Rohit',
 password: '123',
 contactNum: '00000',
 homeNum: '9998889999',
 officeNum: '9998889999',
 emailId: 'dv000d0v@yopmail.com',
 employeeAddress: '10 ,Lakshmi Apartments, Sarai Kale Khan,New Delhi',
 clientId: 'general',
 clientName: 'Restaurant',
 accessLevelId: 'sscaskoo31',
 accessLevelName: 'basic',
 departmentName: 'test',
 departmentId: '58089a9c86337d1894ae1834',
 employeeId: 'EMP1102',
 employeeGrade: 'A',
 employeeGradeId: '1221' }
```

Suggest what i am doing wrong?

Adding the code

```
var user=req.body;
//  var hodId="";
if (req.body.clientId=="general") {
  user.accessLevelName="basic";
}
if (!(req.body.departmentId==null || req.body.departmentId=="")) {
  Departments.find({ '_id': req.body.departmentId },function(err, departments) {
    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    console.log("department"+departments);
    //  user.hodId="test";
    user.departmentName=departments.departmentName;
    var newUser =new User(user);

    newUser.save(function(err,obj) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: "User Name Already Exists"});
      } else {
        var token = jwt.encode(obj, config.secret);
        res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token,msg: 'Successful created new user.',user:obj});
      }
    });
  });
} else{
  newUser.save(function(err,obj) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({success: false, msg: "User Name Already Exists"});
    } else {
      var token = jwt.encode(obj, config.secret);
      res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token,msg: 'Successful created new user.',user:obj});
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a Mongo cursor, maybe you could tell us where this is coming from

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I fetched it from the mongoose model which i had created. How to extract info out of it and store it in variable?

Comment: The id in the above object `_id: 58089a9c86337d1894ae1834,` isn't quoted. Is that the way it is or a mistake?

Comment: how are you retrieving the mongoose model and trying to store the variable? Is it asynchronous? Has the model returned before you try to create the `var`?

Comment: @Craicerjack Its like that only .I did  Departments.find({ '_id': req.body.departmentId },function(err, departments) { console.log(departments); });

Comment: @Craicerjack Yes i am running it in the callback only. I am printing the returned model in the console which is running fine. After that i want to extract one element.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh and what is the output if you do `console.log(departments.hodId)`?

Comment: @Craicerjack Gives me undefined .

Comment: @VaibhavSingh youre leaving something out. have you left anything out of `departments` console log? is it within `[]`? You need to include more code. There isn't enough here to debug.

Comment: @Craicerjack Added code.

Comment: The indentation of your code really makes it very readable.

Comment: @trincot Okay now? Can you answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongoose` `.find()` method returns an Array, not an object. 
The output of `console.log(departmants)` is, or at least should be:

```
 [{ _id: 58089a9c86337d1894ae1834,
  departmentName: 'Software Engineering',
  clientId: '57ff553e94542e1c2fd41d26',
  hodName: 'Mr Shekar Krishna',
  noOfEmployees: 90,
  hodId: 'djekjakejkjkjekajk3j33',
  __v: 0 }]
```

Which means that to access what youre looking for you need to access the first object in the array first.

```
var hodId=departments[0].hodId;
```

Once you have that `var` you can then add it to another user

```
user.hodId = hodId;
```

Comment: You are right about the array . It worked out . But i gave information clearly. Checkout my console screenshot . http://imgur.com/a/cjAPQ

Comment: It doesnt have square brackets :) Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: Thats odd, about the console.log. Yeah didnt mean to come across as scolding, edited answer to change tone. Glad youre all sorted.